# FastAPI Crud design

Tags: python, crud, fastapi, pydantic

I'm working on a Restful API using FastAPI and pydantic and postgres.
I'm looking for schema design that will allow me to get data from user in a POST\PUT requests, enrich the data (default values that shouldn't be set by user or other columns that are deduced by given data), and then insert it to DB.

The project generator (see reference) suggests using schemas UserCreate\UserUpdate etc.
as input to POST \ PUT routes. These objects are passed, in turn, to crud class method that creates\updates the object in the DB. This design will not work since the crud class method needs more information.

Example:
In order to create a user, name, height and weight are required.

```
class UserCreate(BaseMethod):
    name: str
    height: integer
    weight: float
```

User model in database

```
class User(Model):
    name = Column()
    height = Column()
    weight = Column()
    bmi = Column()
```

Crud method need to get name, height, weight and BMI. How do I design my schemas in a way that will make this process as clean as possible?

PS: This is a simple example, I'm not looking for a solution in Database level (I guess that in some databases I can automatically update a column based on other column).

Project Generator Reference:
https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql/tree/master

Thanks

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're actually asking for; you don't need to store bmi, since it can be a calculated property for example? Either using `@property`, but in pydantic you can use a `@root_validator` to compute a value for a field depending on other fields

Comment: So bmi was a simple example. A more complex example is that I fetch data from some url based on his parameters and store it in the database on insert.

Comment: In that case your service class should retrieve the data and insert it into the database; your pydantic input schema wouldn't have that field present, while the pydantic output schema would (if the user should be able to retrieve the content as well). So the answer is the standard "input" / "output" schema for FastAPI - you have one set of relevant fields for input, and one relevant set of fields for output. You move the common fields to a `UserBase`, then inherit from that class to `UserInput` and `UserOutput` (or other names that describe their functionality better)